# Upgrade .Net Framework 2.0 To 4.5

Tags: .net

I have upgraded my asp.net 2.0 project to 4.5 by using Visual Studio 2012. It is building fine, but will I have to test each webform in the browser or will it be converted 100% automatically? Without the .Net Framework 2.0, will the converted project work fine?

Answer (score 14):

If you had upgraded to 3.5 you would be fine since 3.5 simply built on top of 2.0. NET 4.5 is not a perfect superset of 2.0. There are some differences and without seeing ALL of your code no one, not even [Jon Skeet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/), could tell you if the conversion will "work fine".

I would suggest studying [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx) to try and figure out what might have been affected in your upgrade, if anything, and then focusing your testing. Such an approach might actually be more effective than a page-by-page test which would inevitably miss something. It is also possible that the changes from 2.0 to 4.5 might not affect your code-base at all. Here is [an exhaustive list of changes from 3.5 to 4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee941656%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Pay special attention to the ASP.NET parts, there are many.

From that last link there is actually a sample (probably more) that might have you checking each page individually:

> **Page parsing**
>
> The page parser for ASP.NET Web pages (.aspx files) and user controls
>   (.ascx files) is stricter in ASP.NET 4 than in earlier versions of
>   ASP.NET, and it flags more markup as invalid than in earlier versions.
>
> Examine error messages that are produced when a page runs and fix
>   errors that result from invalid markup.

Since there are markup differences, you should really check each page and control for proper rendering.

Comment: Hi Paul, about this answer, you think that just a compile is not a guarantee of a perfect migration?, thank you in advance for the answer.