# Complex .NET solution upgrade from .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, clr, upgrade, solution

There is a need to investigate upgrading of complex solution (30+ projects) from .NET 2.0 to newer version (4.5+).
The only known incompatibility yet known off-the-cuff is Microsoft Moles which are superseded by Microsoft Fakes a while ago and will require additional digging.

I'm looking for some tools and practices that are targeting such migrations. I understand that there will be no silver bullet, but I'm pretty sure there must be some instruments to at least list dependencies of each project, referenced assemblies versions, gather some statistics, etc.

I'm sure that opening solution in VS2013, changing targets for every project to new .NET and trying to re-build with crossed fingers is not a very productive way to solve this problem.

P.S.: There are few alike questions here in SO, but if you can point a place where this one would fit better, do so.

Comment: If your 30 projects are in one single solution, opening VS and changing the target framework might be the most effective way to test it. It can probably be done even before you get an answer here.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049422/upgrade-net-framework-2-0-to-4-5 I've got no tools to recommend, but you may also find this useful, especially the *Breaking Changes* segment http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff962563%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You could also try migrating all your projects at one go with [this tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47bded90-80d8-42af-bc35-4736fdd8cd13), at your own risk.

Comment: @nvoigt Target solution building under 4.5 does not mean it will WORK under 4.5. There will be dozens of errors and incompatibilities. I want to at least make an assumption how much problems will occur, do some analysis before taking any actions. Also, I can't say "I'm starting upgrade, this will take as much time as it will require, result will be ASAP".

Comment: @JWLim Looks like good automation tool. Regarding articles - compiling a list of such resources already, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @Jaded We took a larger solution with heavy interop and a lot of legacy code from .NET 2 to 4 without any issues that our unit tests didn't catch, and even then I don't think we had many. We didn't use any specialised tools, just re-targeting.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Good to know. My problem here would be poor code coverage and even completely passing unit tests (which are randomly failing now btw, restart and everything passes) will not guarantee anything.